# is there any special approach to using (char *) 0 in C?

Tags: c

I understand that `(char *) 0` is a char pointer which points an address at 0. So there is no memory address, out of bound. Often, I hav seen people using it instead of `NULL`, so why don't they just simply use `NULL`? Or, I would like to know, whether there is any special approach to it.

Comment: `NULL` is a way of mentioning "Please don't point anywhere" to the pointer. If you don't make it `NULL` It will be pointing to some or the other address

Comment: `NULL` is a macro. It might be defined as and would expand to `(void*) 0`.

Comment: @alk do you mean any kind of  `(void*) 0` style could be an underlying implementation of `NULL` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*any kind of `(void*) 0` style*"?

Comment: The relevant part of the C11 spec is 6.3.2.3p3: *An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void*`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.* and footnote 66: *The macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant.*

Comment: sorry about my bad english, I mean, (void *) 0 or (char *) 0 instructions different but the effect same.

Comment: Some compilers will complain if you use 0 without typecasting it, but will accept `NULL`. The resulting code is the same after compilation.

Comment: "I understand that (char *) 0 is a char pointer which points an address at 0" - No, it is not! The C standard does not cover using absolute addresses.

Comment: `(char*)0` has a binary representation of `0`, so (as per the Standard citied here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223261/is-there-any-special-approach-to-using-char-0-in-c#comment60078072_36223261) it is a null-pointer constant so its use is equivalent to the use of `NULL`.

Comment: @coladict: A C compiler must not complain! Using the macro `NULL` which should contain an explicit cast to `void *` ist recommended, but not mandatory.

Comment: @alk: Not really. It is not a null pointer constant. And the binary representation of a null pointer need not have all bits zero.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2581522/694576

Comment: @Olaf: "*the binary representation of a null pointer need not have all bits zero.*" I did not say that. However `(char*) 0`'s binary representation *is* `0`.

Comment: I tend to interpret the spec as saying that `(void*)0` is a null pointer constant and `(char*)(void*)0` is a null pointer. I can't speak about `(char*)0` because I've recently been bitten for assuming that there is an intermediate `void*` conversion where there wasn't one. Also related is 6.3.2.3p5, which declares integer conversions to pointer types to be implementation-defined. I'm unsure about whether `(char*)0` falls under that.

Comment: @alk: Either it is a null pointer constant (which it is not), or not (i.e. a valid address in the environment). In the former, there is no requirement for all bits `0`, for the latter this is true.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Agreed. (And I fell into the same trap about the conversion). `(char *)0` is a _null pointer_ of type `char *`. As I see the standard, you in fact cannot convert the _integer-constant_ `0` to a pointer. Even something like `(char *)(uintptr_t)0` or `1-1` would not do the trick standard compliant. All would be easier with a dedicated keyword for a `nullptr`.

Comment: But as absolute addresses are beyond the standard anyway, this is already implementation-specific - as is the representation of a _null pointer_. Problematic is dereferencing, but on most modern architectures physical address `0` is special anyway and for virtual addresses it is easy to reserve this address.

Comment: @Olaf do you mean the absolute `0x0` could be a most common address for null pointer but it is not guaranteed ?

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the clarification. I can mark a detailed answer as a best answer, if you write these as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [*null pointer*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) is strictly speaking no valid address encoding:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.66) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Thus I try to avoid the phrase "address 0" when it comes to *null pointers*, because this is the encoding and a null pointer need not have all bits zero. An architecture could - for instance - use an unused bit in the pointer variables to tag it as invalid. For comparision e.g. bitops would be used instead of compare.

The most common encoding is "all bits zero", though so I will mostly  concentrate on this. This encoding is used because most CPUs have special (and shorter/faster) instructions to store a bit value of `0x0` into a memory cell and compare with/test for `0x0`. Using a special bitpattern also makes comparing two pointers straight forward, using a single compare. The version with setting a dedicated bit would require additional instructions.

Also a value which is at the edge of the address range avoids gaps. This is true for "all bits 1", too, but with less CPU support and address-width dependency.

---

Note that most architectures very well do have a valid **physical** address `0`, so there is in fact a problem with this encoding for a *null pointer* without address translation. Luckily this is typically a special address and not used by normal application code. With virtual memory addressing, it is quite easy just to make address `0x0` invalid, so this is out of discussion.

On some systems, address `0x0` is used for code (PC-boot code/BIOS, embedded systems) or data-accesses (RAM/peripheral hardware registers). Strictly speaking you cannot convert the *integer-constant* `0` to a pointer without invoking the implicit conversion to a null pointer. So, if your system does not use the `0x0` encoding, there is a problem accessing address `0x0` with standard C syntax only. (FYI: this is one reason other languages use a special keyword for a *null pointer constant*, e.g pascal `NIL`, Python `None`, C++ `nullptr`.)

The conversion of an integer to a pointer is implementation defined anyway, as is the *null pointer* encoding. Thus the conversion of a `0` to a pointer is well in-line with the common copy-only integer->pointer encoding without modification of the representation.

A problem arises when dereferencing such a pointer. Dereferencing a *null pointer* is undefined behaviour (UB). As both encodings are identical, there is no way for the CPU to detect if this is a valid access or a *null pointer* dereferencing. Even worse: the compiler is free to exploit this UB and generate arbitrary code (or none at all) if it detects something like `char c = *((char *)0);`.

For a true variable (i.e. not `const` qualified) pointer, this is normally not much of a problem, as that would require dynamic code analysis and in C no code for runtime-checks is generated by the compiler, but for the constant expression above, it **could** very well cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer is a special pointer value that is known not to point anywhere. What this means that no other valid pointer, to any other variable or array cell or anything else, will ever compare equal to a null pointer.

The most straightforward way to get a null pointer in your program is by using the predefined constant NULL, which is defined for you by several standard header files, including , , and . To initialize a pointer to a null pointer, you might use code like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *ip = NULL;
```

and to test it for a null pointer before inspecting the value pointed to you might use code like

```
if(ip != NULL)
    printf("%d\n", *ip);
```

It is also possible to refer to the null pointer by using a constant 0, and you will see some code that sets null pointers by simply doing

```
char *ip = 0;
```

Comment: `NULL` is not a constant, but a macro. C does not have symbolic constants other than _enum-constants_ which are always of type `int`. And the header to be used for this macro alone is `stddef.h`, unless another header is already used (but it does not hurt to include `stddef.h` in general). This because it is guaranteed for **all** implementations, including freestanding.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Whether you say

```
char *p1 = NULL;
```

or

```
char *p2 = (char *)0;
```

or

```
char *p3 = 0;
```

they are all pretty much equivalent.  They're all legal, they'll all work, they'll all initialize the pointer variables to null pointer values.  The differences between them have to do with style, not correctness.

Whoever wrote the code you saw may just have had a different notion about what constitutes good style.

(Now, if you're dealing with pointers of type other than `char *`, using `(char *)0` would be poor, and should at least generate warnings, and under suitably obscure circumstances might actually cause problems.)

Answer (score -1):

NULL represent that the pointer isnt pointing to any address, NULL is a macro for (void *)0

so you can use (char *)0, it would still point to nothing and it'll be easier to explain the code

Comment: if I saw someone using (char *) 0 in code it would be sent straight back to explain why

Comment: i would have asked why NULL? what does it mean?

Comment: NULL is clear enough. It's a guaranteed invalid pointer. It's part of the language, and should be as familair as printf, int and UINT_MAX to the reader. Therefore one asks why (char *)0 has been chosen.

Comment: @Mukesh It would be a bad idea to ask someone you work with what NULL means, because it's defined in the specification of the C language.

Comment: yeah but for beginners i think it shd be clear, and no doubt dis is a bad practice, bt extra knowledge doesnt hurts

Comment: @Mukesh: There is no extra information given why the cast, but actually less. Because it is not clear if really a null pointer is meant by the cast, or the author really intended to have a pointer to address `0x0` - in ignorance about the implicit conversion. Showing the type is nonsense; with the same argument you'd have to cast for every assignment, which you hopefully agree is a really bad idea (I'd instantly fire someone showing up with such code).