# why should the APR_OFFSET op in apache source code minus the base address of null pointer

Tags: c, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why subtract null pointer in offsetof()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568674/why-subtract-null-pointer-in-offsetof)

I hava a question when i read the source code of apache.

in the apr_general.h, there exists a definition as shown below:

```
#define APR_OFFSET(p_type,field) \
    ((long) (((char *) (&(((p_type)NULL)->field))) - ((char *) NULL)))

#endif /* !CRAY */
```

i am juse confused why we should minus the ((char *) NULL)) in this op.

is there anyon that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This trick is used to get an offset (an integer, not pointer) from the beginning of structure

Comment: ups. too fast. to get an offset of a field from the beginning of structure

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But maybe I didn't make myself clear. I mean (char *) (&(((p_type)NULL)->field))) here has got the offset of the field in the struct p_type, but why minus ((char *) NULL)) here.

Comment: (char*)(....) is a pointer to char, not an integer. if you subtract from this value a (char*)(NULL) then you convert it to the integer value. that's it